# Want to import data from firebase realtime database to smart contract writen on solana blockchain

Tags: blockchain, dapps, rust

I am making a token on Solana blockchain and want to give the token to certain uses for that I need data from my firebase Realtime database. I am little bit confuse How to get my data on smart contract. I need to use Chain-link for it ?
This is my first time in doing this type of project and I have very less knowledge in blockchain. please suggest me a way to import data from firebase Realtime database to smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some oracle for it.  The problem with it is that you run the database (so you could theoretically shut it down), so you wouldn't really need a decentralized oracle in any way.  Chainlink could do it (not that they're decentralized), but it might even be overkill unless you don't want to figure it out.  I'd just pass the data over yourself via a script and keep it live. You can make it pretty performant that way and also add in protections if there are any liveness/finality issues